# Unit testing nested lists

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I'm writing unit tests for LINQ repository. I have the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Find_Method_MustReturn_Customer_Orders_ItemsWithinOrder()
{
      Customer c = _rep.Find(6).SingleOrDefault();
      Assert.IsTrue(c.Orders.Count > 0);                        
}
```

I can see whether customer has made any orders. Additionally, I'd like to use LINQ to check whether Orders have any items.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: The options mentioned below differ in what is actually tested. If each Order must have at least one Item, you would use the solution provided by Matt Ellen. If it's OK for Orders to have 0 Items, as long as at least one of the Orders has at least one Item, you can use the solutions given by mathieu and me. A subtle difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will assert that customer has orders and that each order has items.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Find_Method_MustReturn_Customer_Orders_ItemsWithinOrder()
{
    Customer c = _rep.Find(6).SingleOrDefault();
    Assert.IsTrue(c.Orders.Any());      
    Assert.IsTrue(c.Orders.Any(x => x.Items.Any());                        
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't, any will return false if there is no orders

Comment: Forgot to replace IsNotNull with IsTrue. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
var items = 
    From o In c.Orders
    From i In o.Items
    Select i;
Assert.IsTrue(items.Any());
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
Assert.IsTrue(c.SelectMany(x => x.Items).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a `foreach` suffice?

```
foreach(var order in c.Orders)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(order.Items.Count > 0);
}
```